# What's the purpose of the Campaign tab?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, campaign, sms

This might be a no-brainer question, but I'm trying to wrap my head around the purpose of the tab from a functionality and value-add perspective. You send emails from the Email Builder section, and get full reports from the Reporting tab, and all the other functions seem broken down accordingly.

Is this more of a organizational purposes across vast teams and cross-promotional campaigns, or is there a generalized purpose as well, like getting better tracking? Just want to make sure I'm not in the wrong here not using Campaigns at all...

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [**Understanding Campaigns and Associations**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/campaigns/understanding_campaigns_and_associations/):

> A campaign in the Campaigns app is place for organizing content and
>   messages so you or a team can plan, collaborate, analyze and use
>   workflows and approvals around them.
>
> An association is a channel-specific message, content, or activity you
>   want to include in the campaign.

So, basically the campaigns are for grouping cross-channel Marketing Cloud sends.

In practical experience, the data collected isn't very useful -- other than what you can see in your account.  <s>It's not included in any of the system data views or tracking extracts</s>

**EDIT:**  There's a new `Include CampaignID` option on the Tracking Data Extract page.  It includes a `CampaignID` column in the `Sent` extract file.